# Custom HTTPS Server - WebSocket don't work

Tags: node.js, https, websocket, server, proxy

I have a program that serves pages via http (without ssl). I want to make that secure. So I'm writing a nodejs program to use as a proxy server.

The nodejs program (proxy) will accept all the requests from the clients, repeat the requests to the server, receive the response and serve it back to the client.

Everything works except websocets!

I can see that the initial request and response behaves as expected:

request:

```
GET /wstest HTTP/1.1 
Upgrade: websocket 
Connection: Upgrade 
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: qszv9wJR+ldyUuHgwOZOsv/2rQw= 
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 14
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 
Upgrade: websocket 
Connection: Upgrade 
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: qszv9wJR+ldyUuHgwOZOsv/2rQw= 
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 14:17:13 GMT
```

Then the connection stays open and periodically I get some messages from the clients: 8A 00 (in hex)

Also Chrome 76.0.3809.100, Chrome Canary 78.0.3886.0 and FireFox have different behavior, and I not sure how to handle those messages.

Canary gets the message response from server, but Chrome doesn't. And in all browsers the ws connection status is always pending.

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    const https = require("https");
    const net = require('net');

    const source_hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    const source_port = 80;
    const destin_hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    const destin_port = 8443;

    const proxy_opt = {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync("ssl/cert.pfx"),
        passphrase: "###################"
    };

    const proxy = https.createServer(proxy_opt, (req, res) => { serve(req, res); });

    proxy.listen(destin_port, destin_hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on: https://${destin_hostname}:${destin_port}/`);
    });

    const serve = (req, res) => {
        let socket = new net.Socket();

        let isFirst = true;
        socket.on("data", data => {
            let neck = findNeck(data);
            let chunk_stop = data.length - 1;
            let resArrayHead = data.subarray(0, neck).toString().trim().split("\r\n");
            let statusCode = parseInt(resArrayHead[0].split(" ")[1]) || 400;

            let headers = {};
            //headers["Connection"] = "close";
            for (let i = 1; i < resArrayHead.length; i++) {
                let s = resArrayHead[i].split(":");
                if (s.length == 1) continue;
                headers[s[0].trim()] = s[1].trim();
            }

            if (headers["Transfer-Encoding"] == "chunked") { //handle chunked data
                let precrop = neck;

                for (let i=neck+1; i<Math.min(data.length, neck+8); i++)
                    if (data[i - 1] == 13 && data[i] == 10) {
                        neck = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }

                let chunk_size=parseInt(data.subarray(precrop,neck).toString().trim(), 16);
                chunk_stop = neck + chunk_size;

                if (data[chunk_stop-4] == 48 &&
                    data[chunk_stop-3] == 13 &&
                    data[chunk_stop-2] == 10 &&
                    data[chunk_stop-1] == 13 &&
                    data[chunk_stop] == 10)
                    chunk_stop -= 5;
            }

            if (req.url == "/wstest") {
                console.log(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
                //console.log(" > ", headers);
                //console.log(" < ", data);
            }

            if (isFirst) {
                res.writeHead(statusCode, headers);
                res.write(data.subarray(neck, chunk_stop));
            } else
                res.write(data);

            isFirst = false;
        });

        socket.on("error", err => console.log("err: ", req.url, err));

        socket.on("end", () => res.end());

        req.on("data", chunk => {
            socket.write(chunk);
        });

        req.on("end", () => socket.end());

        let reqStringHead = "";
        for (let key in req.headers)
            reqStringHead += key + ": " + req.headers[key] + "\r\n";

        reqStringHead += "X-Forwarded-For: " + source_hostname + "\r\n";

        socket.connect(source_port, source_hostname);
        socket.write(`${req.method} ${req.url} HTTP/1.1\r\n${reqStringHead}\r\n`);
    };

    const findNeck = (data) => { //Finds the point where head and body separates.
        if (data == null && (data.length || 0) < 4) return 0;

        let neck = 0;
        for (neck = 3; neck < Math.min(data.length, 768); neck++)
            if (data[neck - 3] == 13 &&
                data[neck - 2] == 10 &&
                data[neck - 1] == 13 &&
                data[neck] == 10) 
                return neck;

        return 0;
    };
```

Comment: Do you realize that pre-existing code already exists to do what you're doing?  I would think that nginx would do this just fine (along with thousands of other features it contains).

Comment: Thank you jfriend00 for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jfriend00's, I used nginx.

Here is my config file:

```
worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    #https proxy server
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate      ../ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  ../ssl/private.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

        location /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

    }
}
```